# Difficulty troubleshooting performance issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I have a main page in an app that has significant issues when the page is navigated to. I finally narrowed the issue when I added a static class that can be used to write trace information, and time elapsed to the debug out put. I have discovered that when this main page of the app is navigated to (always via hardware back, or nav.goback()) has a greater than 4.5 second delay between the OnNavigatedTo and the Loaded event. At that point, I cannot see any other places in managed code where I can add trace statements to drill down further.

Any suggestions on troubleshooting?

Comment: does this happen in the emulator and/or on a real device?

Comment: it was 3x slower on my Focus, than in the emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try eliminating (commenting out) various items from your XAML until the problem is greatly reduced or eliminated. Likely candidates are databound fields, listboxes, pivot controls with too many items, pivots within panoramas, Converters, etc.

Once you find the source of the slowdown you can begin to work on the cause.

Comment: Thx, yes, I was hoping there was a less time consuming way to find it, but you are correct. I am dying to get my hands on the new perf tools announced at Mix11.


the culprit was this guy:

Comment: DynamicTextBlock [link](http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/alessage/archive/2009/09/16/dynamictextblock-controllo-silverlight.aspx)